# How to bind a number to a variable of type Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing the game "21" in C Sharp, I have a folder with pictures (each picture represents a card from the deck). The question arose: how to attach a needed number to the picture?
For example: when starting the game, 2 images are generated (for example, 8 Hearts and 4 Diamonds). Accordingly, the numbers 8 and 4 should be assigned to the "score" variable, but how to implement this?

```
    public void GenereteCards(GameForm gameForm) // Generates 2 random cards for the player and the dealer
    {
        List<Image> list = new List<Image>();

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"путь к папке"); // Iterates files with .png and assigns them to a list
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.png"))
        {
            list.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
        }

        img = list[rand.Next(0, list.Count)];
        gameForm.card1_dealer.Image = new Bitmap(img);
        list.Remove(img);

        img = list[rand.Next(0, list.Count)];
        gameForm.card2_dealer.Image = new Bitmap(img);
        list.Remove(img);

        img = list[rand.Next(0, list.Count)];
        gameForm.card1_player.Image = new Bitmap(img);
        list.Remove(img);

        img = list[rand.Next(0, list.Count)];
        gameForm.card2_player.Image = new Bitmap(img);
        list.Remove(img);
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do, specifically? Scan the image file content and recognize the card (an image processor) or add metadata to the chosen cards based on the file name, for example? The first case would be pretty advanced and may need some external libraries to handle... the second one is easy, there are a lot of ways to do that, but we need more information about your scenario.

Comment: You can use the filename for mapping the image file with the cards. For example, HeartsK.png, HeartsQ.png, HeartsJ.png, Hearts10.png, and so on. Or even 1.png, ..., 52.png and you know in what order you load the images and map them with the cards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.